# How to add front product page image upload and note textarea box in shopify

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, shopify, shopify-app, wordpress-ecommerce

I need same like this website https://gopupsocks.com/product/custom-breast-cancer-fighter-socks/

How can I do it product page and cart page?

Comment: Can you show us what have you done on your own?

Answer (score 0):

You can Google Shopify Documentation for two easy recipes to follow:

1. Line Item Properties (for the product pages)
2. Cart Notes and Attributes (for cart page and/or other places)

In both cases, you can use those to store any extra information you may want

Note that due to a quirk in Shopify, you won't have a cart to work with until the customer plays with the cart, or you use code to add/delete and item in the cart without them knowing. So be careful when trying the cart attributes out on the front page.

Comment: can you please explain more https://gopupsocks.com/product/custom-breast-cancer-fighter-socks/ i need same look like this send me link of any examples